# Write result from loop into dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to check a list of index's value on a daily basis, for the convenience of reading, I put them into a DataFrame. I'm using Python 2.7

First, I output my answer into a list:

```
index_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7] 
value_list = [20,22,28,29,30,31,32,33]
myarray = []

def minimum(dataframe,value):
    return dataframe['Datetime'][(dataframe["IDXType"] == value)].min()

for i in index_list:
    for value_i in value_list:
        myarray.append(minimum(i,value_i))
```

This will output a 56 lens long list, and then I put it to a dataframe, manually.

```
result = {'df1':pd.Series(myarray[0:8], index=value_list),
  'df2':pd.Series(myarray[8:16], index=value_list),
  'df3':pd.Series(myarray[16:24], index=value_list),
  'df4':pd.Series(myarray[24:32], index=value_list),
  'df5':pd.Series(myarray[32:40], index=value_list),
  'df6':pd.Series(myarray[40:48], index=value_list),
  'df7':pd.Series(myarray[48:56], index=value_list),
  }
result = pd.DataFrame(result)
result
```

It shows 8*7 dataframe. Like below:

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf7gI.png)
I want to ask if there is a short cut for this program? 
Like, directly put my result from the loop into a dataframe?

My list keeps growing therefore I can't afford to fix my code every other day.

Comment: `index_list` is `list` of `DataFrames` with columns `Datetime` and `IDXType` ?

Comment: index is the list of DataFrames with columns. And Datetime and IDXType is the two columns I have to check in the original source data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime':pd.date_range('2015-01-04','2015-01-08'),
                    'IDXType':[20,20,33,33,33]})

print (df1)
    Datetime  IDXType
0 2015-01-04       20
1 2015-01-05       20
2 2015-01-06       33
3 2015-01-07       33
4 2015-01-08       33

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime':pd.date_range('2015-01-04','2015-01-08'),
                   'IDXType':[30,30,21,21,10]})

print (df2)
    Datetime  IDXType
0 2015-01-04       30
1 2015-01-05       30
2 2015-01-06       21
3 2015-01-07       21
4 2015-01-08       10

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime':pd.date_range('2015-01-04','2015-01-08'),
                   'IDXType':[20,20,30,31,31]})

print (df3)
    Datetime  IDXType
0 2015-01-04       20
1 2015-01-05       20
2 2015-01-06       30
3 2015-01-07       31
4 2015-01-08       31
```

```
index_list = [df1,df2,df3] 
value_list = [20,22,28,29,30,31,32,33]
myarray = []
def minimum(dataframe,value):
    return dataframe.loc[dataframe["IDXType"] == value, 'Datetime'].min()
for i in index_list:
    for value_i in value_list:
        myarray.append(minimum(i,value_i))
#print (myarray)          

result = {
'df1':pd.Series(myarray[0:8], index=value_list),
'df2':pd.Series(myarray[8:16], index=value_list),
'df3':pd.Series(myarray[16:24],  index=value_list)
}
result = pd.DataFrame(result)
print (result)
          df1        df2        df3
20 2015-01-04        NaT 2015-01-04
22        NaT        NaT        NaT
28        NaT        NaT        NaT
29        NaT        NaT        NaT
30        NaT 2015-01-04 2015-01-06
31        NaT        NaT 2015-01-07
32        NaT        NaT        NaT
33 2015-01-06        NaT        NaT
```

My solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregating `min`, [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and last remove `index name` by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df1.groupby('IDXType')['Datetime'].min())
IDXType
20   2015-01-04
33   2015-01-06
Name: Datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df = pd.concat([df1.groupby('IDXType')['Datetime'].min(),
                df2.groupby('IDXType')['Datetime'].min(),
                df3.groupby('IDXType')['Datetime'].min()], 
               axis=1, 
               keys=('df1','df2','df3')).reindex(value_list).rename_axis(None)
print (df)       
          df1        df2        df3
20 2015-01-04        NaT 2015-01-04
22        NaT        NaT        NaT
28        NaT        NaT        NaT
29        NaT        NaT        NaT
30        NaT 2015-01-04 2015-01-06
31        NaT        NaT 2015-01-07
32        NaT        NaT        NaT
33 2015-01-06        NaT        NaT
```

---

You can also use more dynamic solution - in `concat` use `list comprehension`, but need add new list for column names in new `df5`:

```
index_list = [df1,df2,df3] 
value_list = [20,22,28,29,30,31,32,33]
namesdf = ['df1','df2','df3']   
df5 = pd.concat([x.groupby('IDXType')['Datetime'].min() for x in index_list], 
               axis=1, 
               keys=namesdf).reindex(value_list).rename_axis(None)
print (df5)  
          df1        df2        df3
20 2015-01-04        NaT 2015-01-04
22        NaT        NaT        NaT
28        NaT        NaT        NaT
29        NaT        NaT        NaT
30        NaT 2015-01-04 2015-01-06
31        NaT        NaT 2015-01-07
32        NaT        NaT        NaT
33 2015-01-06        NaT        NaT
```

Comment: thanks for the reindex, and concat idea. The biggest problem I have is how to write directly into a dataframe, instead of convert to existing one(which means I have to modify my dataframe's size/name/etc. daily). I need help on: loop->list->dataframe to loop->dataframe.

Comment: Hmmm, but why do you need loop? In pandas is the best avoid all loops. It seems I dont understand why my solution is bad, can you explain more?

Comment: well, I have to read from data frame to data frame (in the index_list) to find the minimum value in each specific columns (here is "IDXType") when that column is equal to specific value (in the value_list)...And I don't know any other way around therefore I use nested loops...It could be a bad idea, do you have any other ways in mind?

Comment: I think the best is create 3 sample dataframes and add desired output to question. Are in columns `IDXType` duplicates, so need use `min` ? I try avoid loops, because in pandas loops are very slow (but sometimes are necessary). Also  dont undestand ` I have is how to write directly into a dataframe, instead of convert to existing one` - can you explain more? thank you.

Comment: Yes, IDXType could have a hundred '20's or '22's in it. For "I have is..." part, sorry about my poor wording, I mean "what I want is a way to write directly from my loops to a DataFrame". (P.S. Multiple loops are just as bad as multiple indexes, this is what I learn...now)

Comment: Ok, so give me a time, I try find solution with duplicates in `IDXType`

Comment: Please check my new solution.